# Order multidimensional array with usort error

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi guys i'm trying to order this multidimensional array with uasort but i don't have idea to where is the issue.

It's just the uasort the issue the for, arrays are all ok.

I'll continue investigating where is my issue, thank all for the help.

```
array(4) 
        { ["id_vehiculo"]=> 
                array(4) { [0]=> int(9) 
                           [1]=> int(3) 
                           [2]=> int(1) 
                           [3]=> int(4) 
                         } 
           ["fecha_gps"]=> 
                array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "2014" 
                           [1]=> string(4) "2015" 
                           [2]=> string(4) "2016" 
                           [3]=> string(4) "2017" 
                         } 
           ["id_tipo_posicion"]=> 
                array(4) { [0]=> int(11111) 
                           [1]=> int(22222)
                           [2]=> int(33333)
                           [3]=> int(44444) 
                         } 
           ["cercanos"]=> 
                array(4) { [0]=> int(345)
                           [1]=> int(712) 
                           [2]=> int(10) 
                           [3]=> int(35) 
                         } 
        } 

}

function asd2($matriz_up,$m_vehiculo_distancias){

  $total_vehiculos=count($matriz_up['id_vehiculo']);
  //resetear las keys de vehiculos para coger bien los kms y asignarlos
  $a_vehiculo_distancia = array_values($m_vehiculo_distancias);

    //Asignar ditancias cercanos
    for($i=0;$i<$total_vehiculos;$i++){
       $matriz_up['cercanos'][$i] = $a_vehiculo_distancia[$i];

       echo "id = ".$matriz_up['id_vehiculo'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "pos = ".$matriz_up['id_tipo_posicion'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "fecha = ".$matriz_up['fecha_gps'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "kms = ".$matriz_up['cercanos'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "----------------------<br>";
    }
    echo "----------------------<br>";
    echo "----------------------<br>";
    echo "----------------------<br>";

    uasort($matriz_up, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['cercanos'] - $b['cercanos'];
    });


    for($i=0;$i<$total_vehiculos;$i++){
       $matriz_up['cercanos'][$i] = $a_vehiculo_distancia[$i];

       echo "id = ".$matriz_up['id_vehiculo'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "pos = ".$matriz_up['id_tipo_posicion'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "fecha = ".$matriz_up['fecha_gps'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "kms = ".$matriz_up['cercanos'][$i]."<br>";
       echo "----------------------<br>";
    }

}
$matriz_up['id_vehiculo'][0] = 9;
$matriz_up['fecha_gps'][0] = '2014';
$matriz_up['id_tipo_posicion'][0] = 11111;
$matriz_up['cercanos'][0] = 0;

$matriz_up['id_vehiculo'][1] = 3;
$matriz_up['fecha_gps'][1] = '2015';
$matriz_up['id_tipo_posicion'][1] = 22222;
$matriz_up['cercanos'][1] = 0;

$matriz_up['id_vehiculo'][2] = 1;
$matriz_up['fecha_gps'][2] = '2016';
$matriz_up['id_tipo_posicion'][2] = 33333;
$matriz_up['cercanos'][2] = 0;

$matriz_up['id_vehiculo'][3] = 4;
$matriz_up['fecha_gps'][3] = '2017';
$matriz_up['id_tipo_posicion'][3] = 44444;
$matriz_up['cercanos'][3] = 0;


  $m_vehiculo_distancias[9] = 345;
  $m_vehiculo_distancias[3] = 712;
  $m_vehiculo_distancias[1] = 10;
  $m_vehiculo_distancias[4] = 35;

asd2($matriz_up,$m_vehiculo_distancias);
```

Comment: Try switching to a saner array structure: `[0 => ['id_vehiculo' => ..., ...], 1 => ['id_vehiculo' => ..., ...]]`. All `usort` examples probably assume such a structure, which is also infinitely more reasonable to work with.

Comment: Yes that it's a solution but.. i have to do a lot of changes on the cod..

Answer (score 0):

1. Your array structure is rather insane. You should keep related information together as one unit, not spread out over multiple arrays. You should have one unit looking like:

   ```
   ['id_vehiculo' => 9, 'fetcha_gps' => 2014, 'id_tipo_posicion' => 11111, ...]
   ```

   And then you'd have an array of such arrays:

   ```
   [
     ['id_vehiculo' => 9, 'fetcha_gps' => 2014, 'id_tipo_posicion' => 11111, ...],
     ['id_vehiculo' => ..., 'fetcha_gps' => ..., 'id_tipo_posicion' => ..., ...],
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. Having said this, `usort` won't help you a lot in your case, because you need to be sorting several arrays together in sync. For that, there's [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/array_multisort):

   ```
   array_multisort($matriz_up['cercanos'], $matriz_up['id_vehiculo'], /* list all your arrays here */);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Okey then guys, here the new structure:

```
array(4) {
     [0]=> array(4) {
         ["id_vehiculo"]=> int(9) 
         ["fecha_gps"]=> string(4) "2014" 
         ["id_tipo_posicion"]=> int(11111) 
         ["cercanos"]=> int(345) } 
     [1]=> array(4) { 
        ["id_vehiculo"]=> int(3) 
        ["fecha_gps"]=> string(4) "2015" 
        ["id_tipo_posicion"]=> int(22222) 
        ["cercanos"]=> int(712) } 
     [2]=> array(4) { 
        ["id_vehiculo"]=> int(1) 
        ["fecha_gps"]=> string(4) "2016" 
        ["id_tipo_posicion"]=> int(33333) 
        ["cercanos"]=> int(10) } 
     [3]=> array(4) { ["id_vehiculo"]=> int(4) 
        ["fecha_gps"]=> string(4) "2017" 
        ["id_tipo_posicion"]=> int(44444) 
        ["cercanos"]=> int(35) } 
}
```

Now how i can order by ["cercanos"] ?

Now i'm moving all the information but the ['cercanos'] didn't move dont' know why...

```
$prova = array();

foreach ($a_vehiculo_distancia as $key) {

    $prova[] = $key;

}

array_multisort($prova, SORT_ASC, $matriz_up);
```

Comment: With *this* array structure, your original `uasort` will work just fine. Also, don't post follow-up comments/new questions as answers, please.